# Append smaller numpy.ndarray into a bigger numpy.ndarray

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

**Edit:** 
I guess the actual problem here is that i am appending to a certain dimension in the list, which result inconsistent shape. The length of the zero'th axis would not be the same for each dimension..

So what I actually want to do is

```
>>> a = np.asarray([np.empty((0,3,3)) for i in range(4)])
>>> print a.shape
(4, 0, 3, 3)
>>> a = np.append(a,np.random.randint(4,size=(4,1,3,3)))
>>> print a.shape
(36,)
```

I have to append a lot smaller numpy.ndarrays,  but would like to avoid having the reshape it a to (4,x,3,3) in which x is an increasing value.

**Why I am interested in this?:**

I tried doing the same thing with a list of np.empty arrays but this consumed too much memory.. so i needed a solution that would use less memory, which from different post seemed to possible with numpy arrays.

Comment: You have a shape problem. If you write:
compl[0 , : ] = np.random.randint(5,(1,3,3))
does it do what you want it to do?

Comment: I wanted to append in a for loop.. for each axis = 0

Comment: As I noted in my answer to your previous edition, `append` works with the flattened array if `axis` is not given.  `np.append` is just plain dangerous if you don't take time to read its docs carefully.  Don't treat it like a drop in replacement for the list append.

Comment: Maybe you should show what you did with the list of arrays.  Your current example is still unclear.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you meant to do.

```
>>> compl = np.asarray([np.empty((1,3,3)) for i in range (4)])
>>> print(compl.shape)
(4, 1, 3, 3)
>>> compl = np.append(compl,np.random.randint(5,size=(1,3,3)))
```

Here you need to append it to the whole array `compl` instead of first element `compl[0]`. But it changes the shape.

```
>>> print(compl.shape)
(45,)
>>> print(compl.reshape((5, 1, 3, 3)))
```

Use `reshape` to regain the shape back.

#### Edit

Since you want to change the 2nd dimension, use `axis=1`.

```
a = np.append(a,np.random.randint(4,size=(4,1,3,3)), axis=1)
```

And this by itself retains its shape because of `axis` parameter.

```
>>> a.shape
(4, 2, 3, 3)
```

Comment: not quite.. i want to append in one possible  dimension in the axis = 0

So i intialize axis = 0 to have 5 dimensions.  In a for loop I append np.ndarrays in to each of the 5 dimensions of axis = 0 .

Comment: @mmi I didn't get you. Can you be more precise?

Comment: I added some information.. hopes it clarifies stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating empty (0-sized) array.

```
>>> print np.asarray([np.empty((0,3,3)) for i in range (4)])
[]
```

Also, your error is caused on assignment to array slice, not on the concatenation.

```
 >>> tmp = np.append(compl[0],np.random.randint(5,size=(1,3,3)))
 >>> print tmp # this is perfectly valid
[  1.48219694e-323   1.48219694e-323   1.48219694e-323   4.94065646e-324
   0.00000000e+000   9.88131292e-324   1.48219694e-323   1.48219694e-323
   4.94065646e-324   2.00000000e+000   4.00000000e+000   0.00000000e+000
   1.00000000e+000   4.00000000e+000   2.00000000e+000   4.00000000e+000
   3.00000000e+000   4.00000000e+000]
>>> compl[0] = tmp
ValueErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-63e5075d550e> in <module>()
----> 1 compl[0] = tmp
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (18) into shape (1,3,3)
```

I could not quite understand why you want do such thing, but I guess what you wanted to do was the following.

```
>>> compl = np.append(compl[0],np.random.randint(5,size=(1,3,3)), axis=0)
>>> print compl.shape
(2, 3, 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of array basics

- array size is fixed when created; changing size requires making a new array
- arrays are 'rectangular'; no dimension can be ragged.

`compl` can be made without the list comprehension:

```
In [150]: compl=np.zeros((4,0,3,3))
In [151]: compl
Out[151]: array([], shape=(4, 0, 3, 3), dtype=float64)
```

Because of the size 0 dimension, there are no values in this array.  It has the 4d shape, but 0 elements.

Your `append` statement produces a 1d array:

```
In [152]: np.append(compl[0],np.random.randint(5,size=(1,3,3)))
Out[152]: array([ 2.,  0.,  2.,  2.,  4.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  2.])
In [153]: _.shape
Out[153]: (9,)
```

Why 1d when the inputs are 3d?  Read the docs: `If`axis`is None,`out`is a flattened array.`

You'd get more control using `np.concatenate`:

```
In [155]: compl[0].shape
Out[155]: (0, 3, 3)
In [156]: np.concatenate([compl[0],np.random.randint(5,size=(1,3,3))])
Out[156]: 
array([[[ 4.,  4.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  2.,  3.],
        [ 3.,  0.,  2.]]])
In [157]: _.shape
Out[157]: (1, 3, 3)
```

This is just another reason why I discourage the use of `np.append`.  It behaves as expected when adding one value to a 1d array.  Almost all other uses give problems:

```
In [159]: np.append(np.arange(4),100)
Out[159]: array([  0,   1,   2,   3, 100])
```

I was going to say that even with the correct `concatenate`, assignment to `compl[0]` would produce an error.  Actually it does run, the the result is unexpected:

```
In [161]: compl[0]=np.concatenate([compl[0],np.random.randint(5,size=(1,3,3))])
In [162]: compl.shape     # unchanged, and not ragged
Out[162]: (4, 0, 3, 3)
In [163]: compl[0].shape
Out[163]: (0, 3, 3)
```

We tell it to assign a (1,3,3) array to a (0,3,3) slot (in the (4,0,3,3) array).  Because of the broadcasting rules, that works.  Size `1` dimensions are flexible, and can be replicated to match the target. Here the target is size `0`.

2nd lesson - size 0 dimensions can produce unexpected (though logically correct) results.

---

Your edit is still running into that `flatten` behavior in `append`.  The correct way to use `append` (though I still consider it wrong):

```
In [170]: compl=np.zeros((4,0,3,3), int)
In [171]: np.append(compl, np.random.randint(4, size=(4,1,3,3)), axis=1)
Out[171]: 
array([[[[2, 0, 2],
         [0, 1, 0],
         [0, 1, 2]]],

       ....

       [[[1, 3, 3],
         [2, 3, 3],
         [0, 3, 0]]]])
In [172]: _.shape
Out[172]: (4, 1, 3, 3)
In [173]: compl=np.append(compl, np.random.randint(4, size=(4,1,3,3)), axis=1)
In [174]: compl=np.append(compl, np.random.randint(4, size=(4,1,3,3)), axis=1)
In [175]: compl.shape
Out[175]: (4, 2, 3, 3)
```

---

A better way to construct such an array is to collect subarrays in a list, and assemble them into one array at the end:

Using a list comprehension (or regular loop with list append):

```
In [176]: alist = [np.random.randint(4,size=(4,3,3)) for _ in range(5)]
In [177]: len(alist)
Out[177]: 5
```

`np.array` assembles them with the new dimension at the start:

```
In [178]: np.array(alist).shape
Out[178]: (5, 4, 3, 3)
```

`np.stack` gives more control over the axis:

```
In [179]: np.stack(alist, axis=1).shape
Out[179]: (4, 5, 3, 3)
```

Or build the subarrays with the extra dimension, and use concatenate:

```
In [180]: alist = [np.random.randint(4,size=(4,1,3,3)) for _ in range(5)]
In [181]: np.concatenate(alist, axis=1).shape
Out[181]: (4, 5, 3, 3)
```

`concatenate` (and relatives) all take a list of arrays, so they don't need to be (and shouldn't) applied iteratively. List append is faster.